# Node.js: Save Android-Base64 encoded image as File

Tags: javascript, php, android, node.js, base64

I'm trying to translate my REST-webserver from PHP to Express.js / Node.js.

There is an request which contains an image encoded by Androids Base64 library:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bAOS);
params.put("image", Base64.encodeToString(bAOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

On server-side it should simply decode the data and save the image to a directory. For example, I tried it the following way, using the "base-64" npm-package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64):

```
const image = req.body['image'];
const decodedData = this.base64.decode(image);
this.fs.writeFileSync(PICTURES_PATH + 'image.png', decodedData);
```

But it doesn't seem to decode well, I can't view the file and its size is way to small. This wasn't my only attempt, I tried using Node.js-buffers or another package called "base64-img" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img). The last one worked for test-requests I sent with Postman, but couldn't handle data sent by the app. The console shows the Android-app does not send "data:image/png;base64,..." at beginning, which causes base64-img to fail.

In PHP i just did sth. like:

```
$decodedImage=base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("pictures/".$name.".PNG", $decodedImage);
```

Which was working. I want the app to continue working without updating it, so I need to fix it server-side.

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any library, its all in nodejs.

const image = req.body['image'];
const decodedData = new Buffer(image, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync(PICTURES_PATH + 'image.png', decodedData);

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect and so simple... Don't know why these libraries got so many downloads then...

Comment: `new Buffer` is deprecated, now use `Buffer.from`.